# What is the purpose of assert(false) in an if?

Tags: c, objective-c, assert, assertion

I saw this in an example Apple project called [Rendering Terrain Dynamically with Argument Buffers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/rendering_terrain_dynamically_with_argument_buffers)

```
if (buffers.size() > 1)
{
    assert (false);
    return;
}
```

How would this behave any differently than the simpler `assert(buffers.size() <= 1)`?

Comment: Probably because the `if` was anyway needed for the `return` statement, so the `assert` was placed there for semantical purposes.

Comment: "How would this behave any differently" Because, as sbooth already told you, that wouldn't also return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C `assert` is a macro that does nothing if `NDEBUG` is defined. In this case I'd guess `assert(false)` is inside the conditional to ensure that even if `abort()` is not called (because `assert()` was a no-op due to `NDEBUG` or redefinition) the function returns.